# How to meet "Contour plugin" and "Profile Tool" dependencies in OSX?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

So I have two similar but different issues than my previous question, one I may have mentioned already. When attempting to install the Contour plugin I am told I need matplotlib, which I have on my system (v. 1.1.1).

Also, the Profile Tool is telling me I need Qwt5...I have no idea what this is.

I posted earlier about needing Shapely.wkd for the Profile from Line tool, and received a response that the issue has to do with incompatibility between pyQwt5 and pyQwt.

The Contour plugin does not seem to be related to the Qwt5 issue. Is it possible there is a suite of python modules I am missing on my install?

Install: KingChaos 1.8.0 Lisboa
System: MacOSX 10.7.5

I really enjoy QGIS, but I want it to work correctly.

Comment: Did you install [Shapely Python module?](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely). Also, what does `import matplotlib` return when run in Python console of QGIS?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 309, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named matplotlib

Comment: actually now that you mention it I never did install shapely because I was unsure about how to go about it. I am quite new to this stuff, more of a user if you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond my comments above. A good practice for installing Python modules is to use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Though, for your initial use, I would forgo the setup of a virtualenv at this time as that may complicate your use of those modules from within QGIS (though certainly doable).

As you will be installing pip and Python modules into Mac system areas (`/usr/local` for pip, modules in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`), you will need to preface any install commands in Terminal with `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install Shapely
```

For matplotlib, consider using the [Kynchaos.com installer for that](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python). I'm running 10.7.4 and QGIS (1.8 and master branch build) has no problem finding matplotlib after using said installer.

Comment: Hi there, ran the KyngChaos installer for Matplotlib, attemted to reinstall Contour plugin and receive the following error:  An error has occured while executing Python code:

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4

Python version:
2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]

Comment: I updated numpy from the kingchaos site, but still have the problem. Any advice?

Comment: Can we step backwards for a minute, do I need to install or import these python modules (matplotlib etc.) in to QGIS using the python terminal, after I have installed them on my system? Sorry, I really have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Once you have installed (via pip or a Mac installer) any Python module, it will generally go into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` which is automatically added to the Python sys.path when QGIS's embedded Python interpreter launched. This means PyQGIS any plugin should have those modules available to it. If you want to use those modules in the Python Console, you will have to import them just like in any other Python console (like in Terminal on Mac).

Comment: The fact that you have installed modules, but they are not being acknowledged by QGIS means that QGIS can't find them. This can happen when the Python you use to install the modules is different than the one running in QGIS. For example, if you installed QGIS using the Kyngchaos installer when running Mac OS X 10.6 (which uses Python 2.6) then upgraded to 10.7 (which uses Python 2.7), you would be installing modules via 2.7 while QGIS is still looking in 2.6 site-packages. For this re-install QGIS while running OS X 10.7. Kyngchaos.com installers usually install in both 2.6/2.7 site packages.

Comment: You can compare your QGIS embedded Python interpreter vs. your Python used in Terminal by running the following commands in each and comparing: `import sys;sys.version;sys.path` to find info about the interpreter, `import numpy;numpy.version.version` to compare numpy versions. If they are not the same, re-install QGIS and try again, or check that you have not set any [Python env variables in your shell](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables), causing your modules to be installed in a non-standard location.